# Dynamic Gradient

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, less

I am working on a model that will display a persons genetic population makeup based on country and percentage. I already have the calculations for this data. I need a solution that will interpret this data and display it on the page. The solution I am trying to reach would do the following:

Per the data pulled from the database create an array of Countries, then assign a color from an existing array of colors, color1 = country1... and so on. once the colors are assigned to the countries plugging the colors into a dynamic gradient with dynamic percentages(the percentage that is associated with the country).

I have explored several ways of doing this with no solid solution. My color array includes 10 colors so I tried the less route, but then How do I communicate the assignment of the colors to the countries in JS??? (note: I made a few updates to my less code!!)

```
@yellow: #feea00;
@green1: #85c441;
@green2: #15ae4b;
.gradient (@color; @color2) {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  @color 0%, @color2 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,@color), color-stop(100%, @color2)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  @color 0%,@color2 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  @color 0%,@color2 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  @color 0%,@color2 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  @color 0%,@color2 100%); /* W3C */
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@color', endColorstr='@color2',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.cMatch img.green1 {
  .gradient (@green1; (@green1 + #222));
}
.cMatch img.green2 {
  .gradient (@green2; (@green2 + #222));
 }
.cMatch img.blue1 {
 .gradient (@blue1; (@blue1 + #222));
 }
```

and so on

I also thought just doing a dynamic style in js but I am not sure I approached it the right way to do all the things I need it to.... I would really like a solution that is jquery based and uses the less code above, however I am still in the experimentation stage! The following was my dynamic js attempt.

```
var CountryColor = ['feea00', '85c441', '15ae4b', '0078ff', '36c4bf', '392a7d', 'a02896', 'c52127', 'f09c20', 'e75725'];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Jewish').style.background = "webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%," + CountryColor + "), color-stop(10%,#ffffff), color-stop(11%," + CountryColor + "), color-stop(22%,#ffffff), color-stop(23%," + CountryColor3 + "), color-stop(34%,#ffffff), color-stop(35%," + CountryColor4 + "), color-stop(45%,#ffffff), color-stop(46%," + CountryColor5 + "), color-stop(55%,#ffffff), color-stop(56%," + CountryColor6 + "), color-stop(66%,#ffffff), color-stop(67%," + CountryColor7 + "), color-stop(76%,#ffffff), color-stop(77%," + CountryColor8 + "), color-stop(83%,#ffffff), color-stop(84%," + CountryColor9 + "), color-stop(91%,#ffffff), color-stop(92%," + CountryColor10 + "), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));
});
```

The gradient will have from 1 color up to 10 colors depending on the percentage breakdown of the countries.

Any suggestions anyone has on the best route to go would be much appreciated. My entire site is done in asp.net and C# so if anyone has a suggestion for that route, that would work too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close with the JS example you've got - there are a few issues:

- You're not using the right array syntax to get to the individual colors. Arrays are 0-indexed, and are easiest accessed like ArrayName[i] (so, CountryColor[0] to CountryColor[9]
- jQuery collections use the .css() method http://api.jquery.com/css/ to set backgrounds (not 'style' as you have, which is a straight JS thing).
- You should avoid using bare class selectors in jQuery because they're very slow and inefficient, either use an ID (if each gradient is unique), or qualify your selector with a tag name, or by first finding an element by ID, then looking inside it for the class you want. You can do both - eg: `$('#yourContainer div.Jewish')`.

This example should just about work:

```
var CountryColor = ['#feea00', '#85c441', '#15ae4b', '#0078ff', '#36c4bf', '#392a7d', '#a02896', '#c52127', '#f09c20', '#e75725'];

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.Jewish').style.background = "webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%," + CountryColor[0] + "), color-stop(10%,#ffffff), color-stop(11%," + CountryColor[1] + "), color-stop(22%,#ffffff), color-stop(23%," + CountryColor[2] + "), color-stop(34%,#ffffff), color-stop(35%," + CountryColor[3] + "), color-stop(45%,#ffffff), color-stop(46%," + CountryColor[4] + "), color-stop(55%,#ffffff), color-stop(56%," + CountryColor[5] + "), color-stop(66%,#ffffff), color-stop(67%," + CountryColor[6] + "), color-stop(76%,#ffffff), color-stop(77%," + CountryColor[7] + "), color-stop(83%,#ffffff), color-stop(84%," + CountryColor[8] + "), color-stop(91%,#ffffff), color-stop(92%," + CountryColor[9] + "), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));
});
```

It might make it easier to read your code if you used a JS object to store your colors:

```
CountryColors = {
  Afghanistan: '#00FFCC',
  Albania: '#00FFCC',
  Algeria: '#00FFCC',
  American Samoa: '#00FFCC',
  Andorra: '#00FFCC', 
  Angola: '#00FFCC',  
  Anguilla: '#00FFCC',  
  Antigua and Barbuda: '#00FFCC',
  Argentina: '#00FFCC', 
  Armenia: '#00FFCC',
  Aruba: '#00FFCC'         
}
```

Then you can refer to them by name in your JS:

```
CountryColors.Afghanistan
```

Finally, a nice way to package all this up would be to create a simple jQuery plugin which handles all of this for you, and creates all the browser-specific styles, inserts the white spacers, etc. You could call it like:

```
$('div#Bob').countryColorFill({Albania: 15%, Angola: 45%, Aruba: 40%});
```

The implementation of that is reasonably simple, but probably a bit off track for this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Beejamin! The only problem I have with this example is that I am only using 10 colors and I have more than 10 possible countries, the colors should be assigned to the countries dynamically as they come from the database. So I would not be able to use a js object to store the colors. Hmmm Solution?

Comment: Ah - OK, gotcha. To be honest, I think I would use a separate elements for each country inside a container, rather than trying to do it as a single gradient fill. That way, you could attach other information (for example, a tool tip of the name and percent) to each element. That would allow you to do much more on the server side, too. Does that sound any good? I can make a separate answer for that technique if you're interested.

Comment: hmm I see what your saying, and I thought about that as well, my biggest problem is that the results for most people are going to be so massive because its not just a solitary result of 2 or 3 countries equaling 100%, it will be multiple countries across thousands of segments each segment equaling to 100%. If that makes sense. Doing it with one gradient fill(per segment), then the tooltip will be on each segment showing the countries and their percentage. In most cases there will be thousands of these segments.

Comment: Hmm - I'm not sure if I'm picturing the right thing: Any chance you could make a rough sketch of what you mean?